# Why the ThirdPersonController character is stuttering when he stand on the platform that move up after clicking a button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity version 5.4.1f1 Personal

I have two animations clips. Called them Up and Down.
I have in the Hierarchy a ThirdPersonController with Main Camera as child.

Then i have a empty GameObject i renamed it to: Elevator.
Under the Elevator i have three childs: Platform, Platform1, Capsule.
The Capsule i renamed it to: Button.

To the Button i attached a small script.

Both Up and Down animations clips i set them to be Legacy.
And to the Elevator(GameObject) i added Animation component changed the number of elements in the Inspector to 2 and added the Up and Down animations.

Now when i move the character to the Platform and then click on the Button the Elevator is lifting up. Another click will lift it down.

The problem is when clicking the button and lifting it up it's all stuttering.
And when i click again to lift it down back also stuttering the player in most cases fall/move out of the platform.

Screenshot of the Unity Editor:

[image: Screenshot]

This is the csharp script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Lift : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool pressedButton = false;
    private bool isElevatorUp = false;

    GameObject target;

    void OnMouseOver()
    {
        pressedButton = true;
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        pressedButton = false;
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if(isElevatorUp == false)
        {
            target = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
            target.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Up");
            isElevatorUp = true;
        }
        else
        {
            target = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
            target.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Down");
            isElevatorUp = false;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if(pressedButton == true)
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect(300, 300, 200, 20), "Press to use lift!");
        }
    }
}
```

This is a small video clip i recorded showing the stuttering. I solved the other problems i had with the animations. The only problem now is the stuttering when the player is standing on the Platform and i click the button.

If the player is not on the Platform and i click the button it's not stuttering.
The stuttering start at 51 seconds.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uH1CHrzhUrA&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: @ChuckSavage I created two animation clips Down and Up and recorded the Elevator(GameObject) moving and down. So when i click the button it's playing the animations. It's not that i move the object with the script. And the player is move up only by standing on the Platform and then when i click the button and it's playing the animation it's lifting the player up/down.

Comment: Try parenting the character to the platform while on it.

Comment: @Everts This is working perfect. In the editor i moved the ThirdPersonController to be also a child under the Elevator. Now it's working smooth. I just wonder if it's fine to do it in the editor or should i make it in the script like you said while the player is on the platform make it child of Elevator and if it's not on the platform not making it child ?

Comment: You can add a trigger box to the platform so on enter you parent and on exit you separate.

Answer (score 0):

How is the player being moved up? Is it script that alters its position? I'm guessing it is the collider on the platform.

Seems to me, the collider is acting like a hammer, and hitting the player hard enough to bump them up faster than the platform is moving. So the player seems to jerk, and then is hit again when the platform catches up.

It's in the physics. I'd check that.